# Html php contact form redirection

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form

so I been breaking my head over this, I am pretty new so sorry if I said something wrong. So I got hosting, installed wordpress on it, and I put my html on it, it cointains conctact form written in html and it has separate php file with process. It kindda works, if i test it, it will send me an email, but I put  header('Location: ../front-page.php'); and I get white page with error line, I am pretty sure there is no error cuz well if you go to website, it uses that line and it works just fine, problem is only after submitting form. I am adding a code and putting php in Javascript. Also if possible some extra related questions, is it possible when it redirects to front page also add alert table with success message? And now when I get message, I do not see the one who wrote it email, and its pretty essential, also would be nice to fix . Thank you guys very much!

```js
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $message_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Message is required";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }
  
  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }
      
      $to = 'ignas.levinskas@mail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
           header('Location: ../front-page.php');
          
          $name = $email = $message = '';
       
      }
        
  }
  
}


function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

```html
  
                    <form id="contactform" method="post" action="http://li-designs.com/wp-content/themes/vcs-starter/assets/app.php" >
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name"  required/> 
                        <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required/>
                        <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                    <textarea name="message" type="text" value="<?= $message ?>" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Message" ></textarea>
                        <span class="error"><?= $message_error ?></span>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Replace header('Location: ../front-page.php');   with   echo("<script> window.location.href='../front-page.php'</script>");  and then try

Comment: I still get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in /home3/ignasle/public_html/wp-content/themes/vcs-starter/front-page.php on line 1" and that line is "<?php get_template_part('elements/header'); 
?> , but if you just go to website, it works fine, error only after submitting form rederection

Comment: Error in your `front-page.php`. Redirection is working perfectly.

Comment: But how it can be that? If you go to website it works just fine, and it uses that front-page.php, if there is an error in there then my website wouldn't have header, but it does.